# Select all checkboxes is not working properly

Tags: jsf, checkbox, ms-jet-ace

Here is my code:
when i am trying to click my selectbox all its child selectboxes needs to selectable and when i uncheck the select box all its child selectboxes needs to Unselectable.i tried in following way..but didnt get exact output.can any one help?

```
<ace:dataTable>
    <ace:column>
    <f:facet name="header" >
    <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox partialSubmit="true" value="#{maintainDocumentController.selectAll}"
    valueChangeListener="#{maintainDocumentController.toggleSelectAll}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <div align="center">
    <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{row.selected}"
    partialSubmit="true"
    valueChangeListener="#{maintainDocumentController.uncheckAllSelected}" /></div>
    </ace:column>
    </ace:dataTable>

    public void toggleSelectAll(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
            //this.selectAll=true;
            if (valueChangeEvent != null) {
                if (!valueChangeEvent.getPhaseId().equals(
                        PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION)) {
                    valueChangeEvent.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
                    valueChangeEvent.queue();
                    return;

                }// End if
                }

            pickList=this.searchCriteriaVo.getResultList();
            if (pickList != null) 
            {

                int size=pickList.size();
                for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < size; rowNum++) {
                    SearchCriteriaVo searchCriteriaVO =  (SearchCriteriaVo) pickList.get(rowNum);
                    searchCriteriaVO.setSelected(((Boolean) valueChangeEvent
                            .getNewValue()).booleanValue());
            }}
    }
        public void uncheckAllSelected( ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent )
        {
            //this.selectAll=false;
            if ( !valueChangeEvent.getPhaseId( ).equals( PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION ) )
            {
                valueChangeEvent.setPhaseId( PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION );
                valueChangeEvent.queue( );
                return;
            }// End If
           SearchCriteriaVo tempSearchCriteriaVo=(SearchCriteriaVo)searchCriteriaVo.getDocMaintainTable().getRowData();
            Boolean newValue = ( ( Boolean ) valueChangeEvent.getNewValue( ) ).booleanValue( );
            tempSearchCriteriaVo.setSelected(newValue);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which version of Icefaces this is, and also what is exactly wrong here. But why dont you use ace:ajax? ValueChangeEvent is more like some JSF 1.x method. This way you wont need to control any phase id too.

```
  <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox ...>
      <ace:ajax render="dataTableId" execute="@this" listener="#{bean.listenerMethod}">
  <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox/>
```

Your listener method should take an AjaxBehaviourEvent as an input. You can take the selectBooleanCheckbox component's binded value in the bean and then use it to implement whatever logic you want with it.